# About Django Javascript

Tags: django

I don't know how do write javascript for Django?
Please help me

The following javascript code is correct?

This code is  write in the HTML:
    base.html:
    {% load staticfiles %}

```
index.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
       {
           $("#sampleTable").tablesorter();

   );
</script>

<div class="import">

    <table id="sampleTable" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="{sorter:'metadata'}" style="width:100px">name</th>
                <th class="{sorter:'metadata'}"  style="width:260px">company</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


{% if memo.count > 0 %}
{% for user in memo %}
<div><h3>
    <table id="sampleTable1" class="tablesorter">
        <tbody>
        <td style=" border-bottom:1px solid #0099cc; text-align:center;"><a href="/memo/get/{{ user.id }}/">{{ user.user_name }}</a></td>
        <td style=" border-bottom:1px solid #0099cc; text-align:center;"><a href="/memo/get/{{ user.id }}/">{{ user.company }}</a></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: writing javascript "for django" is in no way different than writing javascript for any other site.

Comment: use javascript easyily as you use in any html file. But there are some syntax errors in your uploaded html code, with the {% if %} and {% for %} blocks please refer the django template docs for the same.

Comment: thank you very much! i should be use the  {% if %} and {% for %}

Answer (score 0):

Django has nothing to do with Javascript by default. It just renders the templates and returns HTML. You write Javascript for Django, like you'd write anywhere else.

And whether that particular code is correct, Run it. If it runs then it's correct, if not, you have some error. But chances are they wont be related to Django.

BTW, your code is incomplete. You haven't closed the `if` and `for` blocks in the template. Also, if you're extending `base.html`, then your HTML should be inside a block that you defined in `base.html`. Please read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) before writing codes.